# How to prove that Newton's method for optimization will converge in one step

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, optimal-control, newton-raphson

I'm studying Advanced motion control and we use Newton's method for iterative optimisation to find the minimum (optimal) control input. So my question is, Consider the following iterative update  algorithm applied   to  find the minimum of
a function f(u), $$u(k+1)= u(k)- \frac{\frac{df}{du}}{\frac{d^2f}{du^2}}$$
If f(u) is a quadratic,  prove   that    the     above   algorithm will  cause u  to
reach   the optimal function input,u*,      in  one step    from    any initial condition.

Comment: So if $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a > 0$, (a) Where is the minimum? and (b) What do you get if you apply one step?